# Can't change images in jQuery thumbnail image gallery

Tags: jquery, css

I am trying to create a simple jQuery image gallery with larger images (550 x 300) displayed every time you click on a small 50x50 thumbnail.

I am using optimizely to modify the elements on a pre-existing page (so I have some limitations from conventional web development) and pulling the image urls from JSON objects within an array. (This part is all working fine).

I can get the thumbnails to display using my code but have encountered a two main problems:

1. Can't get the first image to display on document load:
   Tried to solve this by putting in : $(document).ready(function) and appending an image tag to the relevant div, selecting at position[0] in array, but nothing displayed. (Full code below)
2. When I click on each thumbnail, a new image is added below the first one, (the original image is not replaced with the new image). I tried using the replaceWith method to fix this but it had not effect and got this result instead:

[image]

Here's all the jQuery I'm using:

```
// Select image data as JSON array
var elementData = $('.carousel [data-images]').data('images');
elementData = elementData.replace(/\'/g, '"').replace(/¬/g, '\'');
var imageArray = $.parseJSON(elementData);
var bigImagesLoaded = false;

// Create full "carousel" area enclosing main image + thumb image classes
$('.tab-panel').prepend('<div class="de-carousel"></div>');

// Display first image at position [0]
 $('.de-carousel').append("<img class='de-main-img' src='"+imageArray[0].url+"&width=550&height=300&scale=both&mode=crop'/>");

// Add placeholder main image to carousel area 
// $('.de-carousel').prepend("<img class='de-main-img'src='http://placehold.it/550x300'/>");

// for loop creating thumb-img class and images inside
for (var i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i += 1){
  $('.de-carousel').prepend("<img class='de-thumb-img' value='"+i+"' src='"+imageArray[i].url+"&width=50&height=50&scale=both&mode=crop'/>");
}

$('.de-thumb-img').click(function(){

// Load and add real main image to carousel area 
if(bigImagesLoaded === false){
for (var i = 0; i < imageArray.length; i += 1){
  $('.de-carousel').prepend("<img class='de-main-img' value='"+i+"' src='"+imageArray[i].url+"&width=550&height=300&scale=both&mode=crop'/>");

}
  bigImagesLoaded = true;

}
  $('.de-main-img').css({'display': 'block'});
  var imgNumber = $(this).attr('value');
  deImageDisplayed = parseInt(imgNumber);
   $('.de-main-img').replaceWith('.de-main-img:eq('+deImageDisplayed+')').css({'display':'block'});




});


//Remove old carousel
$('.carousel').css({'display':'none'});

});
```

My CSS:

```
.de-carousel{
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;     
}

.de-main-img {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  display: none;
  width: 550px;
  height: 300px;

}

.de-thumb-img{
  margin-left: 1.0%;
  margin-right: 1.0%;
  margin-bottom: 5px; 
  float: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: inline-block;  
}
```

I couldn't produce a js fiddle unfortunately as I couldn't figure out how to reproduce the images in an array to replicate what I'm trying to do on the actual page.